# Backbone Marionette LayoutView can't find DOM element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm having trouble rendering a Marionette LayoutView and showing a region inside that layout.

My layout file:

```
template: '#fooTemplate',
    regions: {
        barRegion: '.bar'
    }
```

My HTML:

```
<script id="fooTemplate" type="text/template">
    <div id="fooDiv">
        <div class="bar">
        </div>
    </div>          
</script>
```

The code that renders the layout and shows the region:

```
var FooLayout = require('./browserify/path');
var fooLayout = new FooLayout({el:"#fooDiv"})

collectionView = new CollectionView({
    collection: collection
});
fooLayout.render();
fooLayout.barRegion.show(collectionView);
```

I get an error Uncaught Error: An "el" #foo .bar must exist in DOM

What am I missing in LayoutView's functionality? I have a similar example working just fine, but for some reason I cannot replicate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because view is detached from DOM. If you specify `{el:"#fooDiv"}`,  #fooDiv element must be in DOM. I think there should be something like this:

```
<script id="fooTemplate" type="text/template">
    <div class="bar"></div>      
</script>
```

Add #fooDiv in html markup

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="fooDiv"></div>
    ...
</body>
```

and then you can do

```
// "wrap" new Layout around existing div
new FooLayout({ el: '#fooDiv' });
// etc.
```

or

```
// create a new DOM element with the id 'fooDiv':
var fooLayout = new FooLayout({ id: 'fooDiv' });
fooLayout.render();
document.body.appendChild(fooLayout.el); // or $('body').append(fooLayout.el);
```